# OAuth 2.0/OIDC with MFA in Powershell => How to convert to Python

Tags: python, powershell, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Our identidy provider (IDP) only allows MFA (certificates) authenication. If we want to request an OAuth access + ID Token we do it via Powershell in the following form:

```
$url = "IDP_TOKEN_ENDPOINT"
$body = @{grant_type="password";scope="openid";client_id=$client_id}
# how to get certificate Thumbprint: ls cert:CurrentUser\My
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Body $body -CertificateThumbprint <THUMBPRINT_OF_PERSONAL_CERTIFICATE_STORED_IN_WINDOWS>
```

In $response we get the normal OIDC return (with access_token, refresh_toke, ...)

How can I archive the same in python? I tried it with requests_oauthlib  but i do not see any function how can i provide a client certificate - there is just the username/password (https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/clients/legacyapplicationclient.html)? I also want to avoid storing the certificate with a key file in the filesystem, because then i have to store them secure and have to use secure methods for providing the key password.

Any idea?

P.S.: What we want to get. Local script which connects via access token to to the RestAPI. The access token is requested from IDP.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

wreggyl